# Brew Error "unknown regexp options - har" in automake.rb:29 trying to install watchman

Tags: macos, homebrew, watchman

I am trying to install watchman on macOS according to the official [docs](https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/install.html#installing-on-os-x-via-homebrew) via homebrew.

I am getting the following error:

> ❯ brew install watchman
>
> Error: automake:
>   /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/automake.rb:29:
>   unknown regexp options - har
>   ==> Searching for similarly named formulae... This similarly named formula was found: automake To install it, run:   brew install
>   automake
>   ==> Searching taps... Error: No formulae found in taps.

I did run `brew update` before that. Also, I did run `brew install automake`. Neither helped.
Question: What seems to be the problem here? Am I missing dependencies?

Comment: I can run `brew install watchman` without problems. What's the output of `brew doctor`?

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni There is a lot of output. It pasted it here: https://pastebin.com/fH1xcQsm

Comment: You installed third party tools and libraries in `/usr/local` which confuse homebrew. Remove them and try again.

Comment: Under which warning do you mean?

Comment: All these warnings could potentially cause build trouble.

Comment: I am honestly wondering where they are coming from. I almost never use brew. Anyway, will use macports then.

Comment: I don't know where these files come from but certainly not from Homebrew.